# Python O365 module suddenly stopped working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using the O365 python module to send emails. Suddenly it stopped working a few days back (No emails are going through), and I am not able to identify the issue. I'm providing my code for reference. I am using python 3.6

```
from O365 import Message
from O365 import Attachment

def sendemail(to, subj, content, filepath):
        #msg.attach(fileattachment)
        o365_auth = (ID, PASS)
        m = Message(auth=o365_auth)
        m.setRecipients(to)
        m.setSubject(subj)
        m.setBody(content)
        if len(filepath)>1:
            att = Attachment(path=filepath)
            m.attachments.append(att)
        m.sendMessage()


#filepath = "test.csv"
sendemail(to, subj, content, filepath)
```

Comment: No error messages in any log!?

Comment: May be related to the fact that Microsoft borked Office 365 some days ago. Check the news!

Comment: @ThomasSchwärzl No error

Comment: @KlausD. ooh.. I was not aware about this.. Thanks for your info :)